# ASP.NET MVC 4 remember me behavior

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've got the remember me option available on the login page. Could somebody please explain the process? i.e. is going through the logging in process every time user navigates to the page? or is the user constantly logged in and the application only checks the credentials when the user logs off and in again? The reason I ask is that I have `IsEnabled` property on the user table in DB and would like to disable users. But this property doesn't seem to make any difference unless user logs off and in again.
Any Ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the user logs in for the first time with valid credentials, a cookie is created and stored client side. With each subsequent request to the website the cookie is passed to the server and validated to ensure it has not expired and  is valid. If you want to be able to check if your `IsEnabled` should allow a user to access the site, you need to create your own authenticatin logic in the `Application_AuthenticateRequest` event in your Global.asax file.

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Your authentication logic
}
```

You can view a full list of events you can hook into here: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=126

Answer (score 0):

I have used this variant
Add this attribute to your controller

```
public class IsLocked : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (!httpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
            return false;

        var session = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ISession>();

        var userDb = session.Query<Admin>().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Email == httpContext.User.Identity.Name);

        if (userDb == null)
            return false;

        return userDb.Status == null || userDb.Status.Value == false;
    }
}
```